# releasing memory after vm_allocate

Tags: ios, virtual-memory

I would like to create a large, contiguous, partially resident address space region.

I am allocating a large region in my iOS app using `vm_allocate`. iOS automatically finds a suitably large contiguous unused address space region for me and hands me a pointer to that, which is nice.

iOS then automatically backs this with physical memory pages as I write to it, so my app's physical memory usage starts out small and grows as necessary over time. So far so good.

Occasionally I stop using parts of this memory region for a time. My app keeps track of which portions of this region are actually in use at a given time and which are not. However, I cannot seem to identify a way of passing this information to the OS, so I can never shrink my app's physical memory usage (e.g. in response to a low memory warning).

In other, less magical, environments, this codebase reserves a contiguous block of address space, then manually attaches and detaches physical pages as necessary.

Am I missing some vital bit of Apple documentation? - is there a comparable API I could be using instead of `vm_allocate` to achieve this; or, alternatively, is there a way I could place pages of `vm_allocate`d address space back into their initial "uninitialised, automatically mapped on next write" state?

Answer (score 2):

```
kern_return_t kr;
unsigned int nbytes = yourMemroySize;
unsigned int address  ; 

vm_deallocate(mach_task_self(),address, nbytes);
```

I have used this code for releasing memory it works fine.I know this is very very late answer ,i hope it will use some one..

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to release the address space. I want to keep the region of address space reserved, but place some - not all - of the pages within it back into their initial "not backed by real memory, automatically mapped on next write" state that they were in immediately after the original vm_allocate call. Compare the range of options available in other operating systems: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20170113-00/?p=95185